# @PostPersist not called... @PrePersist is... why?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA @Entity class which uses a @PrePersist for quite a while now. Today I wanted to add some functionality where I need the ID of that entity. This ID is generated during persist by a HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE in the database. It is usually set **after** em.persist(entity).

For some unknown reason the **@PrePersist** method is triggered... while **@PostPersist** simply never fires:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("ExtendedEntity.onCreate()");
    }

    @PostPersist
    protected void afterCreate() {
        System.out.println("ExtendedEntity.afterCreate()");
    }
}
```

I'm using a JBoss v4.2 environment with Java v7+, Hibernate v3.3.1.GA and Seam v2.2.2.Final...

*Are there any hidden requirements for @PostPersist to fire?*

Comment: Thinking loud... does org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEventListener interfere with JPA?

Comment: It does interfere... see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For everybody else... Hibernate event listeners seem to interfere with JPA persistence events... after removing the following lines from my **persistence.xml** the @PostPersist callback is triggered.

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-insert"  value="my.hibernate.events.listeners.Listener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-update"  value="my.hibernate.events.listeners.Listener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-delete"  value="my.hibernate.events.listeners.Listener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="my.hibernate.events.listeners.Listener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="my.hibernate.events.listeners.Listener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="my.hibernate.events.listeners.Listener" />
```

We don't even use these anymore... they have just never been disabled completely.

Comment: For posterity, that is because Hibernate actually implements its JPA callbacks via its listeners.  So rather than over-writing the listeners you'd want to make sure that you add listeners; that way both can co-exist (listeners per type are stacked).

Comment: So my settings disabled Hibernate's own listeners it uses for JPA callbacks? Remember... @PrePersist still worked with the above entries. JPA callbacks should work no matter if I use these settings or not.

Comment: Perhaps.  Not disagreeing.  Just explaining what happened.  We have zero enhancement requests for allowing JPA callbacks and Hibernate event listeners to work together.  But be that as it may, they actually can, just not using this XML-based listener config way (which is deprecated now anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it gets called during a commit or a flush. Are you explicitly calling either of these? What I am wondering is maybe there is some delay from when the entity manager is actually persisting to the database. For example, transactions may not be committed until after the response gets written (in web apps).

Also, try using a logger, odd things can happen when calling standard out from web apps.

Comment: The STDOUT was just temporary... I'm using Log4J normally. A manual flush() didn't change anything... see my answer.

Comment: Nice... you didnt mention that you had setup hibernate event listeners in your question.

Comment: Didn't think of these either... I've not used them for a long time but kept a simple logger class configured.